# footer doesn't stay at bottom of page when converting to pdf with PDFKit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, footer, pdfkit

When I render the .html page, everything is OK, I have the footer in the right place, but when converting to PDF, the footer appears in top of the page. Do you have any idea how to correct that ?

This is my CSS file (classical):

```
footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    height:50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: green;
}
```

This is my HTML file (classical too):

```
<h1> HEADER </h1>

Text

<footer> FOOTER </footer>
```

Thanks

**EDIT - The controller method to convert to PDF**

```
 def reporting
      respond_to do |format|

      format.html 
      format.pdf {        render :text => PDFKit.new( post_url('http://localhost:3000/reporting.pdf') ).to_pdf,
                          :page_size=> 'A4',
                          :pdf=> 'TestReporting'
                 }
    end 

end
```

Comment: add a command you use to convert to pdf

Comment: done, my redirection to the pdf page uses the method above